# How to use // (2 slashes) as snippet prefix?

Tags: atom-editor

Here is example of my snippet:

```
'.source.css':
'CSS Comment':
'prefix': 'comment'
'body': '/* [${1:Comment text}]\n------------------------------------------------------------ */\n${2}'
```

So, after typing `//` in *.css files it is not working.
How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

To use the snippet you have to type the value from prefix (in case of the sample you provided it is 'comment') and press the TAB key. You have to replace 'comment' with '//'. There might also be an issue with indentation. This works fine for me:

```
'.source.css':
  'CSS Comment':
    'prefix': '//'
    'body': '/* [${1:Comment text}]\n------------------------------------------------------------ */\n${2}'
```